# Move file in Git with branches

Tags: git, branch

I started a little project followed by Git. With time, the project grew and now the main folder need a big reorganization.

It's an Android project so currently I have this structure :

```
/myProject/
   +-- AndroidManifest.xml
   +-- res/
   +-- src/
   +-- ServerPart/
   +-- [other folders and files]
```

Now, I would like to move to a structure like this :

```
/myProject/
   +-- android/
           +-- AndroidApplication/
                    +-- AndroidManifest.xml
                    +-- res/
                    +-- src/
           +-- AndroidApplicationTest/
   +-- server/
   +-- aFolderwithOtherFiles/
```

First of all, if you have some recommendation for a better structure (best practice) don't hesitate.

The problem is I have several branches. If I do this operation on the master branch for example, when I go to do a checkout on another branch, my structure will explode (and Eclipse might not appreciate it).

Is there a solution to do this refactoring and adapt my branches to "give" them this new structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The merge conflicts arise if too many changes have to be applied during the rebase. Generally, you can help git by not rebasing directly to master, but perform the rebases in smaller steps from commit to commit.

On lowest level, git does not know about "file moves". It only knows about deletion and creation of a new file. If both happen at the same commit, however, and deleted and newly created file are similar enough, however, git assumes that there happened actually a "file move" and behaves appropriately (e.g. when applying commits during a rebase).

So, go like this:

- Split your reorganisation into several commits, each with not more than 50-70 files. This helps git detecting the moves correctly.
- Do not do *any* other changes but *only* the file moves in these commits! Only allowed change is the new package name if source codes change the Java package.
- Apply two tags to your project: "premoves" to the last commit *before* the move commits, "postmoves" to the last *of* the moving commits. I did this in gitk.

Now you have your feature branches all before the commit with the "premoves" tag. Perform the rebases in three steps:

1) Rebase the branch to the "premoves" commit. As there are no file moves before, this is a "normal" rebase with all the usual bells and whistles.

2) Now perform a "git rebase postmoves". That moves your branch over the restructuring. As you main branch only contains the file moves and your feature branch contains the actual content changes to the files, git should be able to handle the situation automatically to a large extent. However, you will get merge conflicts on files you deleted in the feature branch.

Solve these merge conflicts manually by saying that the deleted file of the feature branch should also be deleted on the restructured feature branch (remember, git does not know about the semantics. It just sees: "On the one side, the file was moved, on the other it was deleted. I do not know what to do.") I did this in the git gui by saying "Take remote version" (remote? local? That one which is shown in the diff window as "DELETED")

After this rebase, all files you have changed on the feature branch should be in the restructured position with all their changes still applied. Deleted files of the feature branch are still deleted. Only remaining problem: New files on the feature branch.

Those new files, you have to move manually to their correct new positions. Remember, git only sees files, it has no idea of "moving directory structures around". So, move your new files of the feature branch to their new correct positions and apply git commits for them.

I would suggest to commit these file moves for each file seperately and afterwards use "git rebase -i" and "fixup" the file move commit with at the last commit of the feature branch which touched the file. That prevents too much cluttering.

3) After all this is done, perform the final "git rebase master" (or whatever). This is now also a standard rebase as the restructuring has already happened on the feature branch.

Comment: Your solution is very interesting and effective, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use the `git mv` in master branch to move things around.

When you are ready to apply these things to your branches, you will need to have added and committed your changes.  Then on each branch you will need to check out, and then I would probably do a `git rebase master`

This will apply your changes on top of the folder structure.

Of course, any code that you have that relies on the current structure will need to be changed.

Some of the commands may look like this:

```
 git mv AndroidManifest.xml android
 mkdir android/AndroidApplicationTest
 touch android/AndroidApplicationTest/.gitkeep
 git add .
 git mv ServerPart server
 git status
 git add .
 git commit -m'Restructured application'
 git checkout dev
 git rebase master
 First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
 Fast-forwarded dev to master.
```

Comment: With this method, when I do `git rebase master`, a lot of commit have a conflicts : some files appear as "both deleted" and I don't understand why...
However I think is the "best" solution, even if a lot of commit arise a conlict.